# Kong-OIDC Plugin Installation Issue

Tags: lua, openid-connect, kong

I am installing Kong-OIDC plugin in a Kong docker container and get following error:

Error: Failed installing dependency: https://luarocks.org/lua-resty-openidc-1.6.0-1.src.rock - Failed installing dependency: https://luarocks.org/lua-resty-jwt-0.2.2-0.src.rock - Rockspec format 3.0 is not supported, please upgrade LuaRocks.

Seems like one of the underlying dependency "lua-jesty-jwt" is using Rockpsec format 3.0 version, which is not supported any more. Is there a way to get around this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

I updated the Dockerfile with a previous version of the `kong-oidc` plugin. The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM kong:0.14-centos

LABEL description="Centos 7 + Kong 0.14 + kong-oidc plugin"

RUN yum install -y git unzip && yum clean all

RUN luarocks install kong-oidc 1.0.1
```

But running `docker build -t kong:0.14-centos-oidc` returns this error:

```
Error: Failed installing dependency: https://luarocks.org/lua-resty-openidc-1.2.3-1.src.rock - Failed installing dependency: https://luarocks.org/lua-resty-hmac-v1.0-1.rockspec - Failed installing dependency: https://luarocks.org/luacrypto-0.3.2-2.src.rock - Could not find header file for OPENSSL
  No file openssl/evp.h in /usr/local/include
  No file openssl/evp.h in /usr/include
You may have to install OPENSSL in your system and/or pass OPENSSL_DIR or OPENSSL_INCDIR to the luarocks command.
Example: luarocks install luacrypto OPENSSL_DIR=/usr/local
```

So we need to add `RUN yum install openssl-devel -y` to the Dockerfile. So, if you run again the `docker build` command, you'll get this error:

```
Build error: Failed compiling object src/lcrypto.oError: Failed installing dependency: https://luarocks.org/lua-resty-openidc-1.2.3-1.src.rock - Failed installing dependency: https://luarocks.org/lua-resty-hmac-v1.0-1.rockspec - Failed installing dependency: https://luarocks.org/luacrypto-0.3.2-2.src.rock - Build error: Failed compiling object src/lcrypto.o
```

So we need to install the `gcc` compiler adding `RUN yum install -y gcc` to the Dockerfile. The final result is:

```
FROM kong:0.14-centos

LABEL description="Centos 7 + Kong 0.14 + kong-oidc plugin"

RUN yum install -y git unzip && yum clean all
RUN yum install -y openssl-devel -y
RUN yum install -y gcc

RUN luarocks install kong-oidc 1.0.1
```

Now the container builds successfully, but I think the current [kong-oidc](https://github.com/nokia/kong-oidc) plugin is not maintained anymore.

UPDATE: Check [this repository](https://github.com/blitzrok/kong-oidc-keycloak) to get a working example of the kong-oidc plugin with Keycloak.

Comment: I tried this approach and it works for me for the most part. But in the end I still get an error as below:

`fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 140.82.121.4]: errno=Connection timed out

Cloning into 'lua-resty-hmac'...

Error: Failed installing dependency: https://luarocks.org/lua-resty-openidc-1.2.3-1.src.rock - Failed installing dependency: https://luarocks.org/lua-resty-hmac-v1.0-1.rockspec - Failed cloning git repository.
The command '/bin/sh -c luarocks install kong-oidc 1.0.1' returned a non-zero code: 1`

How do I fix the issue?

Comment: I've implemented the kong-oidc plugin running with Keycloak. Check this repo https://github.com/blitzrok/kong-oidc-keycloak

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of kong-oidc (1.1.0) did not work for me, but I was able to install an older version (1.0.1) without much issue. I did have to install an additional library "openssl-devel" (yum install openssl-devel).

Comment: how did you change your dockerfile? i am having the same problem